# Compare timestamp columns - Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to compare 2 timestamp columns and return the value which is minimum value among the two and wondering is there  a better way than what I have. Note both columns might have values / one of them has value and other could be null. I know about When.otherwise.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import java.sql.Timestamp
 val compareTime = udf((t1: Timestamp, t2: Timestamp) => {
    if(t1 != null && t2 != null && t1.before(t2) ){
     Some(t1)
    }
    else if(t1 != null && t2 != null && t2.before(t1)){
     Some(t2)
    } 
    else if(t1 != null){
     Some(t1)
    } 
     else if(t2 != null){
     Some(t2)
    } 
    else {
       None
    }
  })
 

var df = Seq((1L, "2021-01-04 16:10:00","2021-01-04 15:20:00")).toDF("id","t1","t2")
df = (df.withColumn("t1",to_timestamp($"t1","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
      .withColumn("t2",to_timestamp($"t2","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")))

df = df.withColumn("t3",compareTime($"t1",$"t2"))
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDF is probably unnecessary here - you can use the Spark SQL function `least`:

```
var df = Seq((1L, "2021-01-04 16:10:00","2021-01-04 15:20:00")).toDF("id","t1","t2")
df = (df.withColumn("t1",to_timestamp($"t1","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
      .withColumn("t2",to_timestamp($"t2","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")))

df = df.withColumn("t3",least($"t1",$"t2"))
df.show()
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|                 t1|                 t2|                 t3|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|2021-01-04 16:10:00|2021-01-04 15:20:00|2021-01-04 15:20:00|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

The opposite of `least` is `greatest`, if you want to get the larger one of the two columns.

Note that both `least` and `greatest` will ignore `null` values, but they will return `null` if all input columns are `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(Option(t1) ++ Option(t2)).minOption
```

It should do the same job as your `if`..`else if`..`else` stack.

---

Oops. My bad. Spark doesn't do Scala 2.13.x. Try this instead:

```
util.Try((Option(t1) ++ Option(t2)).minBy(_.getTime())).toOption
```